# Hiding filter input box instead of disabling + tablesorter 2

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I need a little assistance.  I am using a fork of JQuery TableSorter 2 (http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/) to work and filter my tables.  If i dont want certain columns to be used as filter, I simply need to add "filter-false" as a class to the selected column header.

My main question is whether there is a way I can actually hide the filter boxes on the selected columns instead of just disabling them...

Thanks

Emmanuel

Comment: put some code or fiddle... not possible to shoot like blind

Comment: Sorry about that... This is an example of the code that shows the filer inputs and has 2 of them disabled. [link]http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html[/link].  Is there a way of hiding those last 2 disabled input boxes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the default css:

```
/* optional disabled input styling */ 
table.tablesorter thead tr.tablesorter-filter-row input.disabled { 
    opacity: 0.5; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); 
}
```

As seen, a `disabled` class is applied to those disabled filters, so you can use css to either apply `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` to it:

```
tr.tablesorter-filter-row input.disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: For any future readers, the `filters` class has been changed to `tablesorter-filter-row`.

Comment: Will it cause any side effects if I wipe the filter row `$('.tablesorter-filter-row').remove()`?

Comment: @MauricioMorales If you don't want a filter row, set the [`filter_columnFilters` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-columnFilters) to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend simply sticking with:

```
/* optional disabled input styling */ 
table.tablesorter thead tr.tablesorter-filter-row input.disabled { 
   opacity: 0.0; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); 
}
```

As having that one hidden, removes also the table's inner border thus creating unpleasant visual effect.